# Javascript click through the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, click

I have "tabslideout" on jQuery.Script is:

```
$(function(){
    $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
        tabHandle: '.handle',                            
        pathToTabImage: '/images/contact.gif',       
        imageHeight: '122px',                              
        imageWidth: '40px',                                 
        tabLocation: 'left',                              
        speed: '300',                                       
        action: 'click',                                  
        topPos: '200px',                                   
        fixedPosition: true                               
    });
});
```

I want to open this tab through the click on the link like `<a href="">Some Text</a>`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Give the link an id, like this:

```
<a href="" id="some-id">Some Text</a>
```

Then use this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#some-id').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
            tabHandle: '.handle',                            
            pathToTabImage: '/images/contact.gif',       
            imageHeight: '122px',                              
            imageWidth: '40px',                                 
            tabLocation: 'left',                              
            speed: '300',                                       
            action: 'click',                                  
            topPos: '200px',                                   
            fixedPosition: true                               
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you might want to also remove the wrapper `$(function(){ //click event handler });`.

Comment: but i need both. I'm desperate :(

Answer (score 0):

To make your code cleaner, store tabSlideout options and the sliding div in separate variables:

```
var tabOptions = {
    tabHandle: '.handle',                            
    pathToTabImage: '/images/contact.gif',       
    imageHeight: '122px',                              
    imageWidth: '40px',                                 
    tabLocation: 'left',                              
    speed: '300',                                       
    action: 'click',                                  
    topPos: '200px',                                   
    fixedPosition: true                               
};

var slider = $('.slide-out-div');
```

Next, identify your link somehow. Class is usually better than ID:

```
<a href="" class="tabLink">Some Text</a>
```

And finally add a click handler:

```
$('.tabLink').on('click', function(evnt) {
    evnt.preventDefault();
    slider.tabSlideOut(tabOptions);
});
```

Comment: вроде пашет. только не всегда  почему то загружается слайдер. иногда остается внизу страницы в виде фрейма. в чем может быть проблема?